# Why does the negated character class doesn't work as expected?

Tags: vim

```
  xyz mnl pqt aaaa ccc
  yz mn ats aa cbc ddd eee ggg
```

I want to match the first two columns with:

```
 [^\s]*\s[^\s]*\s
```

But this pattern matches up to all columns but the last one. That is:

```
  xyz mnl pqt aaaa
  yz mn ats aa cbc ddd eee
```

I don't understand this in VIM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. `\s` doesn't work in a character class. Use `\S` instead.
2. Prefix the regex with `^` to make it start from the beginning of each line.

```
^\S*\s\S*\s
```

Which matches:

```
xyz mnl pqt aaaa ccc
^^^^^^^^
yz mn ats aa cbc ddd eee ggg
^^^^^^
```